# Why is my OwnPropsEqualTrue function wrecking my code?

Tags: javascript

After spending 3 hours trying to find the source of the

> `Object doesn't support property or method 'exec'`

I am getting, which is spawning many more errors, I've narrowed it down to my function

```
Object.prototype.OwnPropsEqualTrue = function ( )
{
    var true_props = [];
    for ( var this_prop in this ) 
    {
        if ( this.hasOwnProperty(this_prop) && this.this_prop === true ) 
        {
            true_props.push(this_prop);     
        }           
    }
    return true_props; 
}
```

which is meant to act on objects are maps of strings to booleans, e.g.

```
{ "SomeBoolean" : true, "SomeOtherBoolean" : false, "IsInChicago" : false }
```

For some reason the presence of this function is causing the error I mentioned and pointing to the

```
if(isCurrentExternalUser=isExternalUser(),isCurrentExternalUser&&BindClickOnO365SettingsMenu(),isBizStampingDlg=!1,window.location.href.indexOf("IsDlg=1")>-1&&(window.location.href.search(/Upload.aspx/i)>-1||window.location.href.search(/UploadEx.aspx/i)>-1)?(isBizStampingDlg=!0,isUploadDialog=!0):isUploadDialog=!1,window.location.href.indexOf("IsDlg=1")>-1&&window.location.href.search(/aclinv.aspx/i)>-1?(isBizStampingDlg=!0,isSharingDialog=!0):isSharingDialog=!1,isRightToLeft=$("html:first").attr("dir")=="rtl"?!0:!1,uiVersion==15||!isBizStampingDlg)
```

line of a JavaScript library in SharePoint.

Can anyone try to help me understand what i'm doing wrong here? Browser is  IE, btw.

Comment: Extending `Object.prototype` doesn't play well with others. If you use any 3rd party code, you need to make sure they guarantee it's safe to do such extensions. Most probably don't, and for good reason.

Comment: You *may* be able to avoid this issue by making the property non-enumerable. This won't work in old browsers though and doesn't absolutely guarantee that there won't be collisions.

Comment: @squint Then can you help me think of a better way to iterate through a filtered set of properties of an object (from the caller's standpoint)? Cause the only reason I created this is as a helper function to make my code more concise.

Comment: Because such `Object.prototype` extensions will require that all other `for-in` loops use `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)`, it doesn't make your code more concise. It makes it more repetitive and slower. Instead just use a regular function. You can store it as a property on `Object` if you prefer. `Object.OwnPropsEqualTrue = function(obj) { ... };` or just create your own global namespace object, which is probably better.

Comment: Why not define this as an ordinary function, instead of in `Object.prototype`? Then just call `OwnPropsEqualTrue(object)` instead of `object.OwnPropsEqualTrue()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *must* add a method to the Object prototype (and you probably shouldn't), add it with `Object.defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "ownTrueProperties", {
  value: function() {
    return Object.keys(this).filter(function(key) {
      return this[key] === true;
    }, this);
  }
});
```

That'll make the property non-enumerable, so it won't mess up `for ... in` loops.